# construct 4 different scenarios of marginal independence but conditional dependence

Tags: conditional-probability, independence

The question is detailed below:

Construct an example in each of the following settings of three random variables $\alpha, \beta$ and $X$ such that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are marginally independent but they are no longer conditionally independent given $X$.

(a) All three variables are continuous-valued.

(b) $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are continuous-valued and $X$ is binary valued.

(c) $\alpha$ is binary valued, while $\beta$ and $X$ are continuous.

(d) $\alpha$ and $X$ are binary valued, while $\beta$ is continuous.

In the end, you need to check your answer with demonstrating the product of marginal conditional probability is not equal to the joint conditional probability (e.g. $p(\alpha, \beta \vert X)\ne p(\alpha \vert X)\cdot p(\beta \vert X) $)

I was confused by how to check in the last step for 4 different scenarios. (I do not even know how to write such explicit conditional probability at all)

Note that I have already constructed 4 scenarios as follows (not sure whether correct)

(a)
Let these three variables be normal variable with following setting
$$\alpha \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$$
$$\beta\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$$
$$X=\alpha-\beta\sim \mathcal{N}(0,2)$$
(b)
$$\alpha \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$$
$$\beta\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$$
$$
X=
\begin{cases}
0& \alpha>\beta\\
1& \alpha\le\beta
\end{cases}
$$
(c)
$$\alpha \sim p(\alpha)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}& \alpha=1\\
\frac{1}{2}& \alpha=-1
\end{cases}$$

$$\beta\sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$$
$$
X=\alpha\beta
$$
(d) No idea till now.

Comment: Hi, welcome to math.SE! So that we can know how to best help you, please edit your question to include your work on the problem so far

Comment: Hi, I have edited it with my current work now.

Comment: More intuitive and simpler scenarios are welcomed and appreciated!